# Find index of all elements of array1 in array2

Tags: c++, arrays

I have one array that contains a collection of `id` values:

`int arr1 [5] = {110, 111, 112, 113, 114};`

and also have another array that contains the same `id` values, but in some different order:

`int arr2 [5] = {111, 113, 110, 114, 112}`

What is the fastest way to "match" the elements of these two arrays? That is, I'd like some kind of function that takes `arr1` and `arr2` as arguments, and returns a new array of equal size, that gives each of `arr1`'s elements a corresponding index in `arr2`. In this case, the return should be

`{2, 0, 4, 1, 3}`.

Perhaps this is also a question on programming philosophy; I am used to Python, and have always used the Anaconda distribution, which includes functions to perform any kind of statistic, many algorithms, as well as countless what would generally be described as matrix operations, such as the one I describe here, via `NumPy`. Hence, I have gotten in the habit of finding the package that contains the function I need.

But, in C/C++ development, is it uncommon to take this approach? Should I be just writing this simple task myself?

Comment: There are C++ algorithms that do pertain to set operations (`std::set_intersection`, `std::set_difference`, etc.). Maybe you should take a look at them and see if they can solve your problem. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm
On similar notes, maybe you can also use `std::is_permutation` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation

Comment: @Piinthesky nay

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be this:

```
const int size=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
int res [size];
for( unsigned int a = 0; a < size; a = a + 1 ){
    for( unsigned int b = 0; b < size; b = b + 1 ){
         if(arr1[a]==arr2[b]){
             res[a]=b;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Mind that this solution expects the two arrays to have the same size.

I think for C++ you wouldn't import a big library just to use a single easy to do function of it, I would create a function in the same file and simply call it.

Comment: Note that duplicate entries would give duplicated index (instead of possible permutation).

Comment: Right, thanks. A simple implementation like this is easy and attractive. The reason I tended toward asking about something offered by a library is because I need this to be highly optimized-- my arrays in question are at least billions or a trillion elements long.

Comment: I added a break so it can get out of the finder loop when it finds the first id that is the same, so it will be more quick.

Comment: What is the advantage of declaring the loop counter variable as `unsigned`?

Comment: Giving that a and b are iterators that are only going to get bigger, is not useful to give them a negative sign, so instead of going from -2,147,483,647 to +2,147,483,647, making it unsigned makes it represent from 0 to 4,294,967,295 numbers, doubling the capacity of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<std::size_t, N> getPermutation(const std::array<T, N>& base,
                                          const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
    std::array<std::size_t, N> res;
    std::iota(res.begin(), res.end(), 0u);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != res.size() + 1; ++i) {
        for (auto j = i; j != res.size(); ++j) {
            if (arr[res[j]] == base[i]) {
                std::swap(res[i], res[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And that handles duplicates.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86302858a02d1611)

Comment: What's the time complexity on this thing? Would it not be faster to sort both arrays and then do an intersection? Or sort one and then do a binary search?

Comment: Complexity is `O(n²)`. if we sort both arrays, there should be equal (as we search a permutation).